# Jenkins parambuild not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using [Deploy-Dashboard plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/deploy-dashboard/) in Jenkins. I've done all the steps and I'm logged in as a super user but when I access the URI: *{host}/job/{job-name}/parambuild/{parameters}*, the page returns an HTTP Error 404 not found.

I'm at loss, what am I missing?[image]

Update: I got it. I was just missing [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just missing [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/)